# Lock screen slow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lock-screen

For some reason, after bringing up lock screen from suspension,  it does not react to any input from keyboard nor from mouse buttons, the cursor moves fine on screen. It's just the screen is frozen, but then recovers back to normal after about 30 sec.
It started happening about 3-4 months ago. It was fine before that.

I used Stacer removed app cache and cleaned bin to no avail.

OS is ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo 440p.
Dual boot with windows.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a new issue for this on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lpbugreporter/+bug/1916591

(This is not a new question, but a link to the related bug report. I hope it qualifies as useful/answer?)

Comment: having firefox open is the issue for me